# How to create an infinite Observable that produces random numbers at random intervals?

Tags: rxjs

Given a function that generates random numbers, how would you create an infinite Observable that produces random numbers at random intervals?

```
function getRandomNumber() {
  // Assume this function returns a random number, e.g. 198
}

function getRandomDelay() {
  // Assume this function returns a random delay in ms, e.g. 2000
}
```

Here is an example of a desired Observable:

```
---198--------64-------3---2----------18------->  (indefinitely)

3ms     7ms       6ms   3ms     10ms
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```js
const { Observable }  = require("rxjs");

const ob = new Observable(sub => {
  let timeout = null;
  
  // recursively send a random number to the subscriber
  // after a random delay
  (function push() {
    timeout = setTimeout(
      () => {
        sub.next(getRandomNumber());
        push();
      },
      getRandomDelay()
    );
  })();
  
  // clear any pending timeout on teardown
  return () => clearTimeout(timeout);
});

ob.subscribe(console.log);
```

Comment: Thanks! I was trying to use methods like `concatMap()`, but your approach looks simpler.

Answer (score 14):

As an alternative, if you don't want to live in a *confusing timeout-world*, you could write this entirely as a stream:

```
// the stream
const randomizer$ = Rx.Observable.of("")
  .switchMap(() => Rx.Observable
             .timer(getRandomDelay())
             .mapTo(getRandomNumber()))
  .repeat();

// subscribe to it
randomizer$.subscribe(num => console.log("Random number after random delay" + num));


// your utility functions
function getRandomNumber() {
  return ~~(Math.random() * 200)
}

function getRandomDelay() {
  return Math.random() * 1000
}
```

Working example here: http://jsbin.com/zipocaneya/edit?js,console

---

**Alternative:** Create the random number first and then add a delay (if the time of execution does not matter)

```
// the stream
const randomizer$ = Rx.Observable.of("")
  .switchMap(() => Rx.Observable
             .of(getRandomNumber())
             .delay(getRandomDelay()
  )
  .repeat();

// subscribe to it
randomizer$.subscribe(num => console.log("Random number after random delay" + num));
```

---

**Additional note:** Since there is no concurrency or async-operation going on outside of the stream, instead of `switchMap` you could just as well use `concatMap` or `flatMap` - in this case they all work the same.

Comment: Thanks! This looks a bit simpler: `Rx.Observable.of('').concatMap(() => Rx.Observable.of(getRandomNumber()).delay(getRandomDelay())).repeat()`

Comment: Its different though - if your random number creation is depending on some existing, mutable data then it does matter __when__ the actual logic is executed: before or after the delay and the more common case is to have an execution done __after__ a delay - but i'll edit the answer later and add it as an option

Comment: Not sure I understand. In the "Alternative" solution, the number is emitted after the delay, not before. [Example](http://jsbin.com/fizolibuli/1/edit?js,console)

Comment: The time of _emit_ is the same, yes - but the time of _generating_ the random number is different - not sure if this makes a difference for your case, but I have had other cases, where `delay` was added after a complex calculation and by the time of _emit_ the calculated value was already outdated - in that case it is better to first have the delay and then do the calculation (most likely for you it won't make a difference, especially not when you are just using `Math.random()`)

Comment: You do NOT need the repeat() here, it is already an infinite stream.

Comment: @Zolcsi Please check the jsbin-example, remove the `repeat()` and see that it does only emit 1 value, instead of inifinite values.

Comment: Why not simply `Rx.Observable.of(getRandomNumber()).delay(getRandomDelay()).repeat()` ? Otherwise great idea :)!

Comment: @maxime1992 because it will always emit same random number at the very same delay.

Answer (score 0):

Would you take a look at https://github.com/cszredwan/crazyObservable?
I am sure it gonna be of help, this is a custom observable to emit (randomly!) a fixed amount of data over a fixed time horizon.

The problem with your question is that randomly is being used with imprecise meaning. crazyObservable draws a single stream of data of all possibilities of emitting data over the time horizon specified. Of course, you can concat multiples instances of crazyObservable to get desired behavior.

Answer (score 0):

In RxPY 3.0 you can use the following construction:

```
res = rx.generate(0, lambda x: True, lambda x: x + 1).pipe(
         ops.map(lambda x: rx.timer(random.random() * 0.4).pipe(ops.map(lambda y: x))),
         ops.merge(max_concurrent=1),
         ops.map(lambda x: {'count': x, 'value': random.randint(0, 5)}))
```

This produces an infinite stream of random integers between 0 and 5 at random times with interarrival time uniformly distributed on [0, 0.4].

In RxPY 3.0, operations like switchmap or concatmap are not implemented (as in @olsn's reply). The concat_all operation can be achieved by merge with max_concurrent=1.

Edit:

```
rx.generate(0, lambda x: True, lambda x: x + 1)
```

is blocking. Using an infinite vanilla python generator such as

```
import itertools
r = rx.from_iterable(_ for _ in itertools.count(start=0, step=1))
```

is also blocking. You can add some scheduler e.g.

```
from rx.scheduler.eventloop import AsyncIOScheduler
from rx.scheduler import ThreadPoolScheduler
import multiprocessing

scheduler = AsyncIOScheduler(asyncio.get_event_loop())
# scheduler = ThreadPoolScheduler(multiprocessing.cpu_count()) # alternatively

res = rx.generate(0, lambda x: True, lambda x: x + 1).pipe(
         ops.map(lambda x: rx.timer(random.random() * 0.4).pipe(ops.map(lambda y: x))),
         ops.merge(max_concurrent=1),
         ops.map(lambda x: {'count': x, 'value': random.randint(0, 5)}),
         ops.subscribe_on(scheduler)
)
```